# How would a nitrogen-based-photosynthetic microorganism affect Earth and its inhabitants?

Tags: evolution, climate, earth, atmosphere, ecology

Let us assume that mankind genetically-engineered a microorganism which can photosynthesize using the following chemical reaction:

2N2 + 6H2O -> 4NH3 + 3O2.

Then, this microorganism is released into the Earth's oceans and after a period of time, it spread to the entire Earth.

- How would the ecosphere/biosphere get affected?
- How would the global climate & atmosphere get affected?
- What would generally happen to the Earth?
- After a long period of time, how would living things adapt to the changes?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding @user42527! Please take the time to read the [tour] and the [help] section. Currently your question is rather broad. We also try to limit ourselves to one question per post. If you [edit] your question to narrow it's scope it will be likely be better received by the community.

Comment: This is too broad and contains 4 instead of 1 question.

Comment: What does it do with the ammonia? How much does it produce how quickly?

Comment: In real biology [nitrogen is fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_fixation) by [diazotroph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazotroph) bacteria and archaea, such as *[Rhizobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizobia)*; it's an energy-intensive process, so in real life the human-developed [Haber process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process) is used on a massive scale to supplement natural sources of ammonia. Basically, *we are those organisms:* we [synthesize 100 million tons of ammonia per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_production) to grow our crops.

Comment: If the new organism will proliferate in alkaline environment, it can cause devastating effect on Earth's biosphere. Right now ammonia compounds are relatively scarce, and highly beneficial for plant development. However, overabundance will cause alkalinization and make environment inhospitable for traditional organisms.